# Get ModelMetadata for a class in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, modelmetadata, modelmetadataprovider

In Entity Framework 6 I could get the ModelMetadata for a class (myModel) like this:

```
var modelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, myModel.GetType());
```

How can I do the same in .net core 1.1.1?

Answer (score 6):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 there's `EmptyModelMetadataProvider` class which implements `DefaultModelMetadataProvider` which implements `ModelMetadataProvider` which is abstract.  We are able to simply instantiate `EmptyModelMetadataProvider` and call `GetMetadataForType(typeof(MyModel))` and it will return the required metadata.  My particular use for this answer is testing a custom model binder.

Answer (score 5):

ModelMetadataProvider is an ASP.NET feature and it has nothing to do with Entity Framework. In ASP.NET Core you may easily inject a default `IModelMetadataProvider` implementation using the built-in DI:

```
public FooController(IModelMetadataProvider provider) 
{
    var metadata = provider.GetMetadataForType(typeof(model));
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the case was at the time of this answer but `IModelMetadataProvider MetadataProvider` is now a property of `ControllerBase`.